# AntSCript to extract xml tag having specific matching string in attribute value from xml file

Tags: ant, xmltask

I have and XML file as below

```
<sca:composite xmlns:sca="http://www.osoa.org/xmlns/sca/1.0" xmlns:atleastonce="http://www.tibco.com/wrm/policy/atleastonce" xmlns:common="http://xsd.tns.tibco.com/n2/models/common" xmlns:compositeext="http://schemas.tibco.com/amx/3.0/compositeext" xmlns:jdbc="http://xsd.tns.tibco.com/amf/models/sharedresource/jdbc" xmlns:pbu="http://www.tibco.com/wrm/policy/pbu" xmlns:pfe="http://xsd.tns.tibco.com/n2/models/pfe/1.0" xmlns:scact="http://xsd.tns.tibco.com/amf/models/sca/componentType" xmlns:scaext="http://xsd.tns.tibco.com/amf/models/sca/extensions" xmlns:service="http://xsd.tns.tibco.com/bx/amx/model" xmlns:smtp="http://xsd.tns.tibco.com/amf/models/sharedresource/smtp" xmlns:soapbt="http://xsd.tns.tibco.com/amf/models/sca/binding/soap" xmlns:startservicefirst="http://www.tibco.com/wrm/policy/startservicefirst" xmlns:threading="http://www.tibco.com/wrm/policy/threading" xmlns:transactedoneway="http://www.tibco.com/wrm/policy/transactedoneway" xmlns:webapp="http://xsd.tns.tibco.com/amf/models/sca/implementationtype/webapp" xmlns:wrm="http://www.tibco.com/wrm" xmlns:xmi="http://www.omg.org/XMI" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" compositeext:formatVersion="2" compositeext:version="1.0.0.20180112132229840" name="za.co.rmb.dealamendmentsmaintenance" targetNamespace="http://www.example.com/za.co.rmb.dealamendmentsmaintenance" xmi:id="_4EfRQfeKEeeZRvktH3XIjg" xmi:version="2.0">

<sca:reference multiplicity="0..1" name="WorkListService_Consumer1" promote="dealAmendmentsMaintenanceProcessFlow/WorkListService_Consumer" wiredByImpl="false" xmi:id="_AR2UQPeLEeeZRvktH3XIjg">
    <sca:interface.wsdl interface="http://services.brm.n2.tibco.com#wsdl.interface(WorkListService)" scaext:wsdlLocation=".processOut/process/dealAmendmentsMaintenance.xpdl/brm.wsdl" xmi:id="_AR2UQfeLEeeZRvktH3XIjg"/>
</sca:reference>

<sca:reference multiplicity="0..1" name="CreateDailyTasks_Consumer1" promote="dealAmendmentsMaintenanceProcessFlow/CreateDailyTasks_Consumer" wiredByImpl="false" xmi:id="_ATRQkPeLEeeZRvktH3XIjg">
    <sca:interface.wsdl interface="http://www.tibco.com/bs3.0/_8uwIINbzEeWTpucOvGErRg#wsdl.interface(CreateDailyTasks)" scaext:wsdlLocation=".processOut/process/dealAmendmentsMaintenance.xpdl/dealAmendments_segregation.wsdl" xmi:id="_ATRQkfeLEeeZRvktH3XIjg"/>
</sca:reference>

</sca:composite>
```

With ant script i want to extract value in the "interface" attribute under sca:interface, by matching input value in "name" attribute in sca:refernce.

So lets say

if input will be : WorkListService_Consumer1

Expected Output : http://services.brm.n2.tibco.com#wsdl.interface(WorkListService)

Similarly, if
input will be : CreateDailyTasks_Consumer1

Expected Output : http://www.tibco.com/bs3.0/_8uwIINbzEeWTpucOvGErRg#wsdl.interface(CreateDailyTasks)

I tried using various xmltask commands but i am not getting succesfull.

Thanks

Shrijeet Sinha

Comment: I tried below but no value is getting set in property                       
<xmltask source="C:\\Shrijeet\\AMX-BPM-WORK\AUTOMATION-SCRIPTS\\DeploymentFramework\\Deploy\\PromotedReferenceDeployment\\za.co.rmb.xml">
<copy path="/sca:composite/sca:reference[@name='WorkListService_Consumer1']/sca:interface.wsdl/text()" property="property2"/>
</xmltask>
<echo>Value=${property2}</echo>

Answer (score 1):

You almost had the solution, however `text()` is used to reference the inner text of an XML element, such as `<element>This text here</element>`. Here is the syntax for referencing an attribute's value:

```
<xmltask source="xmlfile.xml">
    <copy path="sca:composite/sca:reference[@name='${input}']/sca:interface.wsdl/@interface" property="testproperty"/>
</xmltask>
```